ब्रह्ममुहूर्त: Is it true that whatever we do or plan during this time becomes reality?
Is it true that whatever we do or plan during Brahmamuhurta executes without any hurdles?
Its only applicable for religious practice & Spiritual activities
or
if any high priority thing done or simply thinking about it at that muhurta, concludes successfully.

It will be good for me knowing if any scientific reasons behind this.
